# Differentiation,Mean Value Theorem,Real Analysis

Tags: calculus, analysis, mean-value-theorem

Let $f:\left(a,b\right)\to \mathbb{R}$  be twice continuously differentiable and $x$,$h$ be such that $a<x-h<x+h<b$.

Show that there exists $\xi \in (x-h,x+h)$ so that $\dfrac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^{2}}=f''(\xi)$

My attempt was $\dfrac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^{2}} \\ = \dfrac{\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\dfrac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}}{h} \\ =\dfrac{f'(\xi_{1})-f'(\xi_{2})}{h} \\ =(\dfrac{f'(\xi_{1})-f'(\xi_{2})}{\xi_{1}-\xi_{2}})(\dfrac{\xi_{1}-\xi_{2}}{h})\\ =f''({\xi_{3}})\dfrac{\xi_{1}-\xi_{2}}{h}$.

I could not progress I am sorry if something is obvious. I will be pleased if you show me the last idea or write your own. I just applied mean value theorem while finding numbers $\xi_{1}$ and $\xi_{2}$ and $\xi_{3}$.$\xi_{1}$ comes from the mean value theorem applied in $(x,x+h)$.
$ \\ \xi_{2}$ comes from the mean value theorem on the interval $(x-h,x)$ and $\xi_{3}$ comes from the mean value theorem applied in $(\xi_{1},\xi_{2})$.

Comment: Thank you I had missed them now I clarified.

Comment: Ok, I think now it is a good question. But I would not be surprised if it was a duplicate question. Please search to see if you can find a duplicate question to this.

Comment: It is a duplicate – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bf(x%2Bh)%2Bf(x-h)-2f(x)%7D%7Bh%5E%7B2%7D%7D%3Df%27%27(%5Cxi)%24)

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.